# Ho do I group HTML select option text into columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML select options with text I would like to group into columns that are aligned. I tried using inline-block:

```html
<select>
  <option><span div="display:inline-block;width:3em;">A:</span><span style="display:inline-block;width:5em;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </option>
  <option><span div="display:inline-block;width:3em;">AA:</span><span style="display:inline-block;width:5em;">Fusce efficitur ante</span>
  </option>
</select>
```

I want to get the output:

```
A   Lorem Ipum
AA  Fusce efficitur ante
```

Is there any Twitter Bootstrap for this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we [can't set the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/) for `option` element, except to `background-color` and `color`.

But we can try to use `&nbsp;` and monospaced font like `courier`.

```css
select, option {
  font-family: courier;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>A:&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option>AA:&nbsp;Fusce efficitur ante</option>
</select>
```